# Explanation of Sheikh Uthaymeen saying in Al Qawl ul Mufeed

Tags: hadith-interpretation, islamic-scholar

Assalamou 'Alaikum Warahmatullaahi Wa Barakaatuh..

Some of my friends are saying that Sheikh Uthaymeen said that Allaah can be harmed..

They sent me the following :

Here's his saying :

قوله: ” يؤذيني ابن آدم “: أي: يلحق بي الأذى; فالأذية لله ثابتة ويجب علينا إثباتها

His statement (“yuadhani son of Adam”) meaning: he afflicts me with Al Adhaa (harm). So Adhiyyah for Allah is Affirmed and it is obligatory upon us to Affirm it....

(ref: Al-Qawl-ul-Mufeed Vol 2 pg 356)

Is it true that Sheikh Uthaymeen said this ?

Comment: The meaning is true we may harm/hurt Allah as this is already stated in the Quran, the point maybe whether this is an authentic statement of ibn 'Othaymeen or whether the translation is good enough, but I'm not sure whether this is what you want to have answered.

Comment: Have you actually read the statement in context? Read pages [352-356](https://archive.org/stream/emsktemskt2/qmkt2#page/n352/mode/2up)

Comment: Well I haven't read it, as my friends sent me this.. i don't have the book at my disposal.. so please, can anybofy clarify ? Also, I apologise for not being precised in my question !

Comment: @Salman I linked the online scan in my earlier comment. For text version see [this](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-7339/page-813) and for downloadable pdf see [this](http://ia802703.us.archive.org/1/items/emsktemskt2/qmkt2.pdf)

Comment: @Uma Jazaak Illaah Khayra.. Is there any english version for this ? I am not that familiar to Arabic language..!

Comment: The quote you provided is from a slander book in French, which typically misquote and misinterpret.

Comment: By يؤذيني ابن آدم he is referring to the Hadith Qudsi, narrated in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/117) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/40/2). He says  لا يلزم من الأذية الضرر that أذية does  not imply ضرر and none can inflict ضرر on Allah as proven in [Quran 3:176](https://quran.com/3/176) لَن يَضُرُّوا اللَّهَ شَيْئًا and [Hadith](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/45/70)  إنكم لن تبلغوا ضري فتضروني the translation of the specific part you quoted is provided in III-AK-III's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Sheikh Ibn Al-Uthaymeen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_al_Uthaymeen) said so but this is a partial quote with mistranslation. Here is the full quote with his explanation:

> قوله: " يؤذيني ابن آدم ": أي: يلحق بي الأذى; فالأذية لله ثابتة ويجب علينا إثباتها; لأن الله أثبتها لنفسه، فلسنا أعلم من الله بالله، ولكنها ليست كأذية المخلوق; بدليل قوله تعالى: {لَيْسَ كَمِثْلِهِ شَيْءٌ وَهُوَ السَّمِيعُ الْبَصِيرُ} [الشورى: من الآية11] ، وقدم النفي في هذه الآية على الإثبات؛ لأجل أن يرد الإثبات على قلب خال من توهم المماثلة، ويكون الإثبات حينئذ على الوجه اللائق به تعالى، وأنه لا يماثل في صفاته كما لا يماثل في ذاته، وكل ما وصف الله به نفسه; فليس فيه احتمال للتمثيل.
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> His saying: "the son of Adam hurts me" i.e., afflicts hurt to me; the hurt [*athā*, Arabic: أذى] of Allah is proven as Allah Himself used this word, and who is more knowledgeable about Allah than Allah Himself. But this is not hurt similar to that which would be afflicted on His creations, and the proof is that there is nothing like Allah; He is the Hearing, the Seeing ([Surat Ash-Shuraa 42:11](https://quran.com/42/11)). In this verse, Allah preceded proof [the Hearing, the Seeing] by disproof [nothing like Allah] so that anyone who dares liken Allah [to His creations] be prevented from doing so. The proof of afflicted hurt should then be in a manner proper to Allah may He be exalted. His attributes are not to be likened as He Himself is not to be likened [to His creations]. There is no possibility of representation [of hurt] in what Allah has attributed to Himself.

**NOTE.** The reference is *Al-Qawl al-Mufīd 'ala Kitāb at=Tawhīd* (Arabic: القول المفيد على كتاب التوحيد), Saudi Arabia: Dār Ibn Al-Jawzi, Mar. 2003, Gloss of Vol. 2, pp. 244.

The concept of *athā* (Arabic: أذى) of Allah is mentioned in the Qur'an:

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ يُؤْذُونَ اللَّهَ وَرَسُولَهُ لَعَنَهُمُ اللَّهُ فِي الدُّنْيَا وَالْآخِرَةِ وَأَعَدَّ لَهُمْ عَذَابًا مُّهِينًا
>
> Indeed, those who abuse Allah and His Messenger — Allah has cursed them in this world and the Hereafter and prepared for them a humiliating punishment.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Ahzab 33:57](https://quran.com/33/57)</sub>

The word *yu'thūn* (Arabic: يؤذون) was translated as abuse (Sahih International's translation), annoy (Abul Ala Maududi, Mufti Taqi Usmani, Muhsin Khan, And Yusuf Ali's translation), hurt (Dr. Ghali's translation), malign (Pickthall's translation), speak evil things (Shakir's translation), insult (Abdul Haleem's translation), and offend (Dr. Mustafa Khattab's translation). The reason for such wide variation in their choice of words is that the word *athā* in the Arabic language does not have an exact equivalent word in the English language.

In the same book, Shiekh Ibn al-Uthaymeen explains in the gloss of Vol. 2, pp. 241, saying that the word *athā* (Arabic: أذى) refers to being hurt in the same manner as when one hears improper words or comes across a bad or strong smell (e.g., that of onions or garlic). This hurt does not imply harm (*darar*, Arabic: ضرر) as harm cannot be inflicted upon Allah may He be exalted ("O My servants, you can neither do Me any harm nor can you do Me any good." , Arabic: إِنَّكُمْ لَنْ تَبْلُغُوا ضَرِّي فَتَضُرُّونِي وَلَنْ تَبْلُغُوا نَفْعِي فَتَنْفَعُونِي, quoting [Sahih Muslim 45/70/2577](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/45/70)). The same concept is mentioned in the gloss of Vol. 2, pp. 248.